# Suppose that $S = \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ is the set of all positive integers and that $P(\{s\}) = 2^{-s}$ for all $s \in S$.

Tags: probability, continuity

Suppose that $S = \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ is the set of all positive integers and that $P(\{s\}) = 2^{-s}$ for all $s \in S$.

(a) Find a sequence of events $\{A_n\}$ such that $\{A_n\} \uparrow A_k$ where $A = \{2k+5 | k = 1, 2, 3 \}$

(b) Compute P(A), where $A = \{2k+5 | k = 1, 2, 3 \}$ by using continuity of P.

---

My attempt:

(a)

$$A_n = \{7, 9, 11, \cdots, 2n+5\}$$

(b)

Let $A_n = \{7, 9, 11, \cdots, 2n+5\}$. Then by finite additivity,
$P(A_n) = P(7) + P(9) + \cdots + P(2n+5) = 2^{-7} + 2^{-9} + \cdots + 2^{-5 - 2n}$

$=1/4\frac{1-(1/4)^n}{1-1/4} = 1/3(1-(1/4)^n)$. But since $\{A_n\} \uparrow A$ we have $P(A) = \lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1/3(1-(1/4)^n) = 1/3$.

Is this right?

Comment: Your computation of $P(A_n)$ seems to be wrong.  Except for this what you have done is fine.

Comment: I forgot the $\cdots$ for $2^{-5-2n}$ which I just added, is that what you meant?

Comment: You forgot the fact that the sum starts with $2^{-7}$. I think $P(A_n)=\frac 1 {96} (1-\frac 1 {4^{n}})$

Comment: Thank you. Forgot geometric series properties